# Can Berserker's Fury be ended before the end of the encounter?

Tags: dnd-4e

The new **Barbarian** subclass the **Berserker** plays both a defender role and a striker role.  He switches to striker mode by entering into his **Berserker Fury**.

Pg.44 of *Heroes of the Feywild* says "...you enter your **Beserker Fury** until the end of the encounter."

Is it possible to end **Beserker Fury** before the end of the encounter and thus use **Defender Aura** to reactivate defender mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**

While a fury has multiple entry points (the use of a primal power or a minor action while bloodied) the only listed end state is "end of the encounter." There are no utilities or daily powers indicated that could break a fury.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the End of the Encounter text and no mention of ending it I would say that you remain in the fury until the end of the encounter.

I'd also say that flavor wise this makes sense, you are in a berserker's fury and wouldn't be able to just "calm down."